# Is it possible for someone to clone Itachi Uchiha?

Tags: naruto, boruto

Recently, in *Boruto*, we found out that Koji Kashin of *The Kara* is a clone of Jiraiya, created by Amado to kill Jigen. But, is it possible to create a clone of Itachi Uchiha?

Amado used the DNA from Jiraiya’s severed arm, which had been ripped off by Pain before the rest of the body was thrown into the sea to clone him. It was never explained what was done with Jiraiya’s arm, and Kabuto could not find it during the war. But perhaps Amado had come to the place first and collected the arm before anyone else came looking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer and question is *mostly speculative,* but it *should* be able to get answered based off what has been revealed in the plot.

---

One fact that **should be** certain is:

- Ideally, any character in the Naruto/Boruto universe should be able to be cloned, provided that he or she who wants to duplicate that person has access to that persons DNA. This follows the same principle as [*Summoning: Impure World Reincarnation*](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation), minus the body sacrifice that the jutsu requires.

Considering the above, one should be able to clone *any* character in Naruto as long as they have access to their DNA. Kabuto explained:

> [image]

- The above manga panel explains all that is needed to bring someone back via Edo Tensei is the person who is being resurrected DNA. As long as anyone can access Itachi's DNA, they should be able to clone him for whatever purpose they need to.

---

**(Again, this is speculative, because the question is speculative in a way, but can be answered based off of what is revealed in the plot and facts given throughout the series.)**

Comment: a shorter answer would be, one should be able to clone itachi for whatever reason provided they have access to his dna

Comment: If we consider only NS, then yes. Itachi was reincarnated using Edo tensei (cc @Sayed).

Comment: @ᴅᴀɴɪᴇʟ cool, maybe we will see itachi again in boruto, they can also get DNA by time travel as it was done before by Sasuke and boruto...

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami yeah, practically **anyone** should be able to provided that they have access to the dna of one who wants to clone. im not entirely sure what things carry itachi's dna, but as long as you find his he can be cloned

Comment: I have added an answer elaborating OP's second para and explained why Kabuto couldn't find Jiraiya's arm and the reason behind Jiraiya not getting resurrected in final arc of NS.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli yeyeye, would've been super cool for adult sasuke to run into itachi, even tho that arc was a filler

Comment: @ᴅᴀɴɪᴇʟ yup, it will be cooler if Itachi teaches something to Sarada, we know Sasuke character and I believe he does not disclose anything about Itachi to his family.

Answer (score 1):

Although the main question is answered by @Daniel, I want to highlight and elaborate the second para of OP's question.

> Amado used the DNA from Jiraiya’s severed arm, which had been ripped off by Pain before the rest of the body was thrown into the sea to clone him. *It was never explained what was done with Jiraiya’s arm, and Kabuto could not find it during the war.* But perhaps Amado had come to the place first and collected the arm before anyone else came looking for it.

Yes, it is true that Jiraiya wasn't revived in the final arc of NS by Kabuto through Edo Tensei and the reason for that is quite different in anime and manga. In Masashi Kishimoto's original story in manga, Kabuto claims that he could get a big enough sample of Jiraiya's DNA to reanimate him, but Obito says not to push his luck. *However*, in the anime, Kabuto simply says that he can't reanimate Jiraiya because his body is at the bottom of the sea. Considering all the other powerful ninja Kabuto brings back, this is a weak excuse, especially since he can go through great lengths to bring back DNA of dead ninjas. The real reason Jiraiya isn't reanimated is to protect the integrity of the character's emotional final scenes in NS. But if we consider the context of the narrative, his omission in the final war is certainly odd.

Now, the absence is somewhat explained in Boruto. Kashin Koji is thought to be a clone of Jiraiya because Kara were heavily involved in genetic manipulation and the concept of clones is already known in Boruto i.e. Shin. *So, Kara might have took the severed arm of Jiraiya for themselves leaving Kabuto with nothing to work with.* Kara have been operating in secret for years, and they were artificially creating ninjas appears to be their chief recruitment method. Even if Kabuto did manage to get some DNA, he cannot ressurect him because Kashin Koji was already a clone of him and the rule of Edo Tensei is that the body must be dead in the first place in order to get reanimated.

Source: https://screenrant.com/boruto-naruto-jiraiya-reanimation-plot-hole-kashin-koji/

Comment: I believe many people do not know about this plot hole, nice information.

Comment: this is great answer for why Kabuto didn't resurrect Jiraiya in the great ninja war.